# C# Reference object in a collection by a string instead of integer

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a collection of objects stored in a List.

I would like to address the an object by using a string name instead of an integer.

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>;
Foo item = fooList["Foo Name"]
```

instead of:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>;
Foo item = fooList[0]
```

I was thinking that I need to create a collection class that inherits from List, but from there, I'm not sure.

Comment: What about a Dictionary?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`Dictionary<string, Foo>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is the type you want.

Comment: Arghhhhh! I knew it would be simple ;p

Comment: nice thing is, you can use any object as the key, not just string or int

Answer (score 2):

Joren's answer is the go-to, but if you need to preserve sequential order for some other logic, AND the name you want to refer to the object by can be a member of that object, than a little Linq can also do the trick:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>;
Foo item = fooList.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.Name == "Foo Name");
```

You could put this into an "indexer" property of a custom collection that derives from list:

```
public class MyList:List<Foo>
{
   public Foo this[string name]
   {
      get { return this.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.Name == "Foo Name"); }
   }
}
```

...which allows you to get your exact desired syntax, while maintaining sequential ordering (which is not guaranteed with a Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `Dictionary<string,Your_Object_type>;`

Since you don't care about sequential order, this is the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a Dictionary.  Then you can do:

```
var fooList = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();
fooList.Add("Foo Name", new Foo());
var item = fooList["Foo Name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `List<T>`, you need a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

```
Dictionary<string, Foo> fooDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();

fooDictionary.Add("Foo Name", new Foo());
Foo myFoo = fooDictionary["Foo Name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write your own indexer like

```
    public datat-type this[int x]
    {
    get{
    //getter code
    }
    set{
    //Setter code
    }
    }
    public data-type this[string x]
    {
    get{
    //setter code
    }
    set{
    //setter doe
    }
    }
```

Comment: In and of itself, this will accomplish nothing. The core logic to turn "foo name" into 0 is the more important part of the logic.

Comment: he also stated that if he inherits to make a new class

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a dictionary, one could use List.Find with a predicate.  Note, this is an alternative to dictionary but gives flexibility on how the item (object) is found.  Name would be a string property of Foo.

Example:

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>; 
Foo item = fooList["Foo Name"] 

//Find Using Inline 
Foo foo = fooList.Find(delegate(Foo f) { return f.Name == "Foo Name"; });
```